# Change sleep times in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, sleep

How do I change the sleep time of my desktop Windows 7 system?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22077974/446106 for a command-line answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hit the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key and type "power options", hit enter.
Click on "Change Plan Settings" by the selected power plan.
Change the value for "Put the Computer to Sleep" to what you want.

Done! :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Windows XP**

Step 1:
Click Start Menu, select Control Panel.

Step 2:
Click on Power Options, and the Power Options Properties configuration window will appear.

Step 3:
In the System Standby field, enter any amount of time you would like the computer to sit idle before automatically going into standby, or entirely turn off automatic standby.

**Windows Vista**

Step 1:
Click Start Menu to load the Help Center.

Step 2:
Enter Power Management Settings in the search field.

Step 3:
Click Change Power Management settings.  The Power Options window will then appear.

Step 4:
On the left side of the window, click Change when the computer sleeps.

Step 5:
Change the Put the computer to sleep entry with the desired amount of time you will allow the computer to sit idle before it sleeps, or automatically turn off its option to enter into Sleep mode.

**Windows 7**

Step 1:
Click Start Menu, select Control Panel.

Step 2:
Click on Power Options, select change setting for the plan : Balanced

Here you have two option -

2.1  Turn off the display

2.2  Put the computer to sleep

or

Step 3: click on Edit power plan

Here you have two option -

3.1  Turn off the display

3.2  Put the computer to sleep

Comment: The OP stated Windows 7.

Comment: Yes, it will work for windows 7 too, once you move into power option, you need to edit info.

Comment: Can you include this point in your answer. Thanks.